# OpenOfice Sheet name as variable in formula | Scalable

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, excel-indirect

I want to sum daily results from every Sheet. I need to take Sheet name dynamically and be able to drag formula to calculate other day result.

I have formula:    `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($A20&".C$3:C$29975");INDIRECT($A20&".$B$3:$B$29975");"=Clicks:";INDIRECT($A20&".$A$4:$A$29976");$B20)`
It takes Sheet name from `A20` - cool. It takes numbers from `C$3:C$29975` - cool.

But in next column I need it to became     `INDIRECT($A20&".D$3:D$29975")` and so on. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDIRECT has a R1C1 version. To use this version in OpenOffice you have to set the second parameter to 0. See: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function

In the case of R1C1 notation only, Calc uses the ! character to separate the sheet identifier.

So

```
=INDIRECT($A20&"!R3C"&COLUMN(C1)&":R29975C"&COLUMN(C1);0)
```

should be useable in OpenOffice and draggable to the right.

OK, the above works. But

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3;COLUMN(C1);1;;$A20)&":"&ADDRESS(29975;COLUMN(C1);1))
```

will be more compatible.

For ADDRESS see: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ADDRESS_function

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you Axel. It seems like advanced level. Could you please explain what R3C means? Tried to google it but didn't find answer. Tried just dump paste your code but it gives err 502

Comment: Sorry, I've just no OpenOffice Calc here. I have edited my answer, according to the documentation, it should be alright now. If you get errors furthermore, please comment again. But I can then test only evening today.

Comment: Alex, maybe you could write formula in Excel format as well? I just tried to open file on Excel and it does not convert properly, shows #REF!

Comment: Both versions should be compatible with Excel also. If you get #REF, are you sure, the sheet name in $A20 is correct?

Comment: For the first version it has to be a English version of Excel, because in other language versions the R1C1 (Row1Column1) may be different. For German version for ex. it is Z1S1 (Zeile1Spalte1). So use the second version for more compatibility.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I thought it will be compatible.
I have formula:
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3;COLUMN(C1);1;;$A2)&":"&ADDRESS(29975;COLUMN(C1);1));INDIRECT($A2&".$B$3:$B$29975");"=Clicks:";INDIRECT($A2&".$A$4:$A$29976");$B2)

Where A2 is sheet name. Maybe you see any errors?

Comment: Yes, `INDIRECT($A2&".$A$4:$A$29976")` the sheet identifier separator is ! in Excel, not . like in Calc.

Comment: Works! Thank you one more time